# same function name: possible conflict between dplyr and other packages, e.g. GenomicRanges, IRanges

Tags: r, namespaces, dplyr

I have a simple questions on name space regarding **dplyr**.

Some functions in **dplyr** have the same name in other packages, like in **GenomicRanges**, **IRanges**. If I load a package depends on a function which is masked by **dplyr**, how could I know that my codes work correctly.

Take an example,

```
library(DESeq2)
```

Output omitted…

```
library(dplyr)
```

> Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
>
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:GenomicRanges’:
>
> ```
> intersect, setdiff, union
> ```
>
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:IRanges’:
>
> ```
> collapse, desc, intersect, setdiff, union
> ```
>
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:BiocGenerics’:
>
> ```
> intersect, setdiff, union
> ```
>
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
>
> ```
> filter, lag
> ```
>
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
>
> ```
> intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
> ```

If now I used the function name **collapse**, it will call the function in **dplyr**.

I could explicitly to use  IRanges::collapse, however, it will be tedious to do it every time. If I just blindly use **collapse**, does R know which **collapse** to use depending on data?

Besides, if I load a package later depends on **collapse** in **IRanges**, does that package know where to find the right function to use?

Could someone give me reference on this topic?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+masked+

Comment: Thanks, it seems there is not a easy answer.

Comment: it looks like most of the base functions, especially the ones in dplyr, are just amended to be S3 methods and just call the base functions as normal (for example `dplyr:::union.default`), so they would work as expected. I don't think it is a good idea to use functions with the same name as common base functions, but it looks like hadley has left the functionality intact. I can't comment on the other packages

Comment: Thanks @rawr, I will be careful about them.